openpyxl line charts: how do I assign random markers to the lines?
I managed to create a simple line chart almost to my requirements:
c1 = opxl.chart.LineChart()
c1.style = 2
data = opxl.chart.Reference(wsh, min_col=2, min_row=24, max_col=maxc, max_row=29)
labels = opxl.chart.Reference(wsh, min_col=1, min_row=25, max_col=1, max_row=29)
c1.add_data(data, titles_from_data=True)
c1.set_categories(labels)
c1.height = 8.75
c1.width = 20
wsh.add_chart(c1,"A4")

This generate a chart like this with my data:

Now, I would like each line to have a different marker (square, triangle, circle, X, etc..).
I know how to do it series by series, but with my data the number of series may vary and I cannot go one by one, I need a sort of automatic marker. Excel can do this.
I tried to play with all the style numbers up to 15, but they seem to affect only the color palette of the lines. Numbers 2 and 10 gives somewhat automatic various colors which is what I need.
Anyone would know how to do setup line markers automatically?
Thanks!

You can certainly loop and set the marker to auto for all series added to the chart
...
c1 = opxl.chart.LineChart()
c1.style = 2

data = opxl.chart.Reference(wsh, min_col=2, min_row=24, max_col=maxc, max_row=29)
labels = opxl.chart.Reference(wsh, min_col=1, min_row=25, max_col=1, max_row=29)
c1.add_data(data, titles_from_data=True)
c1.set_categories(labels)

### Add auto marker for each series that the chart has
for s in c1.series:
    s.marker = opxl.chart.marker.Marker('auto')

c1.height = 8.75
c1.width = 20
wsh.add_chart(c1,"A4")

Example
All series markers are set to auto so when chart is created it auto sets the marker.


This worked like a charm, I did not know there was the option 'auto'. Thanks!
